# WordCount example runs in Eclipse, but not in terminal

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I tried running first of the [WordCount examples](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example) and it works in Eclipse (I have Windows 7 OS), but not in shell, using the command:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.MinimalWordCount
```

I have installed Maven and configured JAVA_HOME and Path variables and so on, however, I'm not sure what I must have missed. This is the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Tutorial 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Tutorial ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Java\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x8
6_64\eclipse\workspace\Tutorial\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ Tutorial --
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ Tutorial ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.MinimalWord
Count
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.011 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-03T01:11:57+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java 
(default-cli) on project Tutorial: An exception occured while executing the Java 
class. com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.MinimalWordCount -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception-
```

I am in the dark about how to proceed and would very much appreciate ideas of where to look next and other things to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the command in the directory containing com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.MinimalWordCount?

Comment: Yes, I am. It wouldn't even get this far otherwise, it would return a different error (`[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM`).

Comment: did you run mvn install?

Comment: Maven is properly installed. If I test with

`mvn -install`

it returns:

`Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:3
7+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Comment: I have set `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` variables, too.

Comment: Well, actually, 'mvn install' makes sure the dependencies specified in the pom are pulled down and installed (rather than having anything to do with maven itself being installed).  You just run 'mvn install' in the directory you plan to run the class from later.

Comment: I've tried now this (mvn install in the directory) as well, but after when I try to run the example again, it returns the same error as before. :/

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into an issue with the documentation.

The command line you are using should work if you have cloned [GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples). The mention of the particular repo to clone is way back in "[getting started](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started-maven)", not at all obvious if you head straight to [WordCount Example Pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example).

But if you generated the project from the [Cloud Dataflow Plugin for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started-eclipse) (or via a [Maven archetype](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started-maven)) then the examples are placed into your Java package. So instead of `com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.MinimalWordCount` you will use the name `my.java.project.MinimalWordCount`, where `my.java.project` is whatever package name you chose when you created the project.

Or if you have cloned the SDK itself from [GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK) then you will need to add `-pl examples` to your command line. This is because the SDK's repository is factored into maven modules; this flag instructs maven to run in the context of the `examples` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-module maven project (DataflowJavaSDK, not DataflowJavaSDK-examples), you can do `mvn compile` in the top directory, then `cd` into `examples` and then issue the `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=...` command there.